# RMUIF react, material ui, firebase - auth flow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to get the [RMUIF](https://docs.rmuif.com/getting-started) template to work.

At the moment, I'm stuck trying to get the auth flow to perform.

In the local environment, sometimes I can actually sign in. However, with no changes to the code, on other occasions, I get an error that says:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'code' of
> undefined (anonymous function)
> src/components/SignInDialog/SignInDialog.js:197

that code block has:

```
.catch((reason) => {
              const code = reason.code;
              const message = reason.message;

              switch (code) {
                case "auth/invalid-email":
                case "auth/user-disabled":
                case "auth/user-not-found":
                case "auth/wrong-password":
                  this.props.openSnackbar(message);
                  return;

                default:
                  this.props.openSnackbar(message);
                  return;
              }
            })
```

When I try commenting that block out, I get no error but the console log says:

> Uncaught (in promise) undefined

In the production environment, I can't use any of the sign in flows. Each of sign in with password, send signin link and reset password flows just hang - the form does not submit. The console log shows:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: e is undefined.

I know the creator of this project is busy with other projects and not maintaining this project- but before I give up trying to figure out how to use this, has anyone been able to solve the auth issues?

Has anyone managed to get the auth flow in this template to work?

Full code for the sign up is:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import validate from "validate.js";

import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

import {
  Dialog,
  DialogTitle,
  DialogContent,
  DialogActions,
  Typography,
  Tooltip,
  IconButton,
  Hidden,
  Grid,
  Button,
  Divider,
  TextField,
} from "@material-ui/core";

import { Close as CloseIcon } from "@material-ui/icons";

import AuthProviderList from "../AuthProviderList";

import constraints from "../../data/constraints";
import authentication from "../../services/authentication";

const styles = (theme) => ({
  closeButton: {
    position: "absolute",
    right: theme.spacing(1),
    top: theme.spacing(1),
  },

  icon: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(0.5),
  },

  divider: {
    margin: "auto",
  },

  grid: {
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(2),
  },
});

const initialState = {
  performingAction: false,
  emailAddress: "",
  password: "",
  errors: null,
};

class SignInDialog extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = initialState;
  }

  getSignInButton = () => {
    const { emailAddress, password, performingAction } = this.state;

    if (emailAddress && !password) {
      return (
        <Button
          color="primary"
          disabled={!emailAddress || performingAction}
          variant="contained"
          onClick={() => this.sendSignInLinkToEmail()}
        >
          Send sign-in link
        </Button>
      );
    }

    return (
      <Button
        color="primary"
        disabled={!emailAddress || performingAction}
        variant="contained"
        onClick={() => this.signIn()}
      >
        Sign in
      </Button>
    );
  };

  resetPassword = () => {
    const { emailAddress } = this.state;

    const errors = validate(
      {
        emailAddress: emailAddress,
      },
      {
        emailAddress: constraints.emailAddress,
      }
    );

    if (errors) {
      this.setState({
        errors: errors,
      });
    } else {
      this.setState(
        {
          errors: null,
        },
        () => {
          this.setState(
            {
              performingAction: true,
            },
            () => {
              authentication
                .resetPassword(emailAddress)
                .then((value) => {
                  this.props.openSnackbar(
                    `Sent password reset e-mail to ${emailAddress}`
                  );
                })
                .catch((reason) => {
                  const code = reason.code;
                  const message = reason.message;

                  switch (code) {
                    case "auth/invalid-email":
                    case "auth/missing-android-pkg-name":
                    case "auth/missing-continue-uri":
                    case "auth/missing-ios-bundle-id":
                    case "auth/invalid-continue-uri":
                    case "auth/unauthorized-continue-uri":
                    case "auth/user-not-found":
                      this.props.openSnackbar(message);
                      return;

                    default:
                      this.props.openSnackbar(message);
                      return;
                  }
                })
                .finally(() => {
                  this.setState({
                    performingAction: false,
                  });
                });
            }
          );
        }
      );
    }
  };

  signIn = () => {
    const { emailAddress, password } = this.state;

    const errors = validate(
      {
        emailAddress: emailAddress,
        password: password,
      },
      {
        emailAddress: constraints.emailAddress,
        password: constraints.password,
      }
    );

    if (errors) {
      this.setState({
        errors: errors,
      });
    } else {
      this.setState(
        {
          performingAction: true,
          errors: null,
        },
        () => {
          authentication
            .signIn(emailAddress, password)
            .then((user) => {
              this.props.dialogProps.onClose(() => {
                const displayName = user.displayName;
                const emailAddress = user.email;

                this.props.openSnackbar(
                  `Signed in as ${displayName || emailAddress}`
                );
              });
            })
            .catch((reason) => {
              const code = reason.code;
              const message = reason.message;

              switch (code) {
                case "auth/invalid-email":
                case "auth/user-disabled":
                case "auth/user-not-found":
                case "auth/wrong-password":
                  this.props.openSnackbar(message);
                  return;

                default:
                  this.props.openSnackbar(message);
                  return;
              }
            })
            .finally(() => {
              this.setState({
                performingAction: false,
              });
            });
        }
      );
    }
  };

  sendSignInLinkToEmail = () => {
    const { emailAddress } = this.state;

    const errors = validate(
      {
        emailAddress: emailAddress,
      },
      {
        emailAddress: constraints.emailAddress,
      }
    );

    if (errors) {
      this.setState({
        errors: errors,
      });

      return;
    }

    this.setState(
      {
        performingAction: true,
        errors: null,
      },
      () => {
        authentication
          .sendSignInLinkToEmail(emailAddress)
          .then(() => {
            this.props.dialogProps.onClose(() => {
              this.props.openSnackbar(`Sent sign-in e-mail to ${emailAddress}`);
            });
          })
          .catch((reason) => {
            const code = reason.code;
            const message = reason.message;

            switch (code) {
              case "auth/argument-error":
              case "auth/invalid-email":
              case "auth/missing-android-pkg-name":
              case "auth/missing-continue-uri":
              case "auth/missing-ios-bundle-id":
              case "auth/invalid-continue-uri":
              case "auth/unauthorized-continue-uri":
                this.props.openSnackbar(message);
                return;

              default:
                this.props.openSnackbar(message);
                return;
            }
          })
          .finally(() => {
            this.setState({
              performingAction: false,
            });
          });
      }
    );
  };

  
  signInWithAuthProvider = (provider) => {
    this.setState(
      {
        performingAction: true,
      },
      () => {
        authentication
          .signInWithAuthProvider(provider)
          .then((user) => {
            this.props.dialogProps.onClose(() => {
              const displayName = user.displayName;
              const emailAddress = user.email;

              this.props.openSnackbar(
                `Signed in as ${displayName || emailAddress}`
              );
            });
          })
          .catch((reason) => {
            const code = reason.code;
            const message = reason.message;

            switch (code) {
              case "auth/account-exists-with-different-credential":
              case "auth/auth-domain-config-required":
              case "auth/cancelled-popup-request":
              case "auth/operation-not-allowed":
              case "auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-environment":
              case "auth/popup-blocked":
              case "auth/popup-closed-by-user":
              case "auth/unauthorized-domain":
                this.props.openSnackbar(message);
                return;

              default:
                this.props.openSnackbar(message);
                return;
            }
          })
          .finally(() => {
            this.setState({
              performingAction: false,
            });
          });
      }
    );
  };
  

  handleKeyPress = (event) => {
    const { emailAddress, password } = this.state;

    if (!emailAddress && !password) {
      return;
    }

    const key = event.key;

    if (event.altKey || event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey || event.shiftKey) {
      return;
    }

    if (key === "Enter") {
      if (emailAddress && !password) {
        this.sendSignInLinkToEmail();
      } else {
        this.signIn();
      }
    }
  };

  handleExited = () => {
    this.setState(initialState);
  };

  handleEmailAddressChange = (event) => {
    const emailAddress = event.target.value;

    this.setState({
      emailAddress: emailAddress,
    });
  };

  handlePasswordChange = (event) => {
    const password = event.target.value;

    this.setState({
      password: password,
    });
  };

  render() {
    // Styling
    const { classes } = this.props;

    // Dialog Properties
    const { dialogProps } = this.props;

    const { performingAction, emailAddress, password, errors } = this.state;

    return (
      <Dialog
        fullWidth
        maxWidth="sm"
        disableBackdropClick={performingAction}
        disableEscapeKeyDown={performingAction}
        {...dialogProps}
        onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}
        onExited={this.handleExited}
      >
        <DialogTitle disableTypography>
          <Typography variant="h6">Welcome back</Typography>

          <Tooltip title="Close">
            <IconButton
              className={classes.closeButton}
              disabled={performingAction}
              onClick={dialogProps.onClose}
            >
              <CloseIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </Tooltip>
        </DialogTitle>

        <DialogContent>
          <Hidden xsDown>
            <Grid container direction="row">
            {/* 
              <Grid item xs={4}>
                <AuthProviderList
                  performingAction={performingAction}
                  onAuthProviderClick={this.signInWithAuthProvider}
                />
              </Grid>
            
              <Grid item xs={1}>
                <Divider className={classes.divider} orientation="vertical" />
              </Grid>
            */}
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Grid container direction="column" spacing={2}>
                  <Grid item xs>
                    <TextField
                      autoComplete="email"
                      disabled={performingAction}
                      error={!!(errors && errors.emailAddress)}
                      fullWidth
                      helperText={
                        errors && errors.emailAddress
                          ? errors.emailAddress[0]
                          : ""
                      }
                      label="Email address"
                      placeholder="john@clark.com"
                      required
                      type="email"
                      value={emailAddress}
                      variant="outlined"
                      InputLabelProps={{ required: false }}
                      onChange={this.handleEmailAddressChange}
                    />
                  </Grid>

                  <Grid item xs>
                    <TextField
                      autoComplete="current-password"
                      disabled={performingAction}
                      error={!!(errors && errors.password)}
                      fullWidth
                      helperText={
                        errors && errors.password ? errors.password[0] : ""
                      }
                      label="Password"
                      placeholder="&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;"
                      required
                      type="password"
                      value={password}
                      variant="outlined"
                      InputLabelProps={{ required: false }}
                      onChange={this.handlePasswordChange}
                    />
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Hidden>

          <Hidden smUp>
          {/* 
            <AuthProviderList
              gutterBottom
              performingAction={performingAction}
              onAuthProviderClick={this.signInWithAuthProvider}
            />
          */}
            <Grid container direction="column" spacing={2}>
              <Grid item xs>
                <TextField
                  autoComplete="email"
                  disabled={performingAction}
                  error={!!(errors && errors.emailAddress)}
                  fullWidth
                  helperText={
                    errors && errors.emailAddress ? errors.emailAddress[0] : ""
                  }
                  label="E-mail address"
                  placeholder="john@clark.com"
                  required
                  type="email"
                  value={emailAddress}
                  variant="outlined"
                  InputLabelProps={{ required: false }}
                  onChange={this.handleEmailAddressChange}
                />
              </Grid>

              <Grid item xs>
                <TextField
                  autoComplete="current-password"
                  disabled={performingAction}
                  error={!!(errors && errors.password)}
                  fullWidth
                  helperText={
                    errors && errors.password ? errors.password[0] : ""
                  }
                  label="Password"
                  placeholder="&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;"
                  required
                  type="password"
                  value={password}
                  variant="outlined"
                  InputLabelProps={{ required: false }}
                  onChange={this.handlePasswordChange}
                />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Hidden>
        </DialogContent>

        <DialogActions>
          <Button
            color="primary"
            disabled={!emailAddress || performingAction}
            variant="outlined"
            onClick={this.resetPassword}
          >
            Reset password
          </Button>

          {this.getSignInButton()}
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    );
  }
}

SignInDialog.propTypes = {
  // Styling
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,

  // Dialog Properties
  dialogProps: PropTypes.object.isRequired,

  // Custom Functions
  openSnackbar: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(SignInDialog);
```